How can I add a string on pdf file with shipping label layout using python?
I'm trying to add a string on a shipping label which is under pdf. I'm not 100% sure if using python to do this task but as a noob that just got into coding world, it's the only language that I can write something down.
The goal is simple. I want to add a string on the pdf file but the output pdf file should have the same text layout as the original file. I successfully read the pdf file with PdfMiner library and now converting the line of string to original shipping label layout as PDF is a little struggle for me.
Is there any method to rearrange lines of strings with divided sections and layout as pdf?
If other language has the better approach, please let me know!
Initial File and Output Goal
For better understanding please see the initial file and output goal.
Thank you so much in advance.

Hey KJ, 1) Thanks for letting me know the general rules of this forum. I may post wrong subject on this forum and hopefully nobody got offended. 2) The goal is trying to add a string next to "REF: " with around 0.8 inch space. I managed to read the shipping label as string but I have no clue how to get them output as the same layout as the shipping label layout. 3) My team need to see the final output file as pdf. so if there's any method to arrange the layout as same as shipping label and eventually convert to pdf, it will also work!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you'd like to take @KJ's recommendation of a command-line tool which has a command to add a stamp, some options include pdfstamp (which requires Java) or pdfcpu which has precompiled binaries
